# sql group by and max and other values

Tags: sql, group-by

i have a table that contains:

```
itemid inventdimid datephysical transrefid
10001   123         2015-01-02   300002
10002   123         2015-01-03    3566
10001   123         2015-02-05    55555
10002   124         2015-02-01     4545
```

The result i want

```
itemid inventdimid datephysical transrefid
10001   123           2015-02-05   555
10002   123           2015-01-03    3566
 10002   124         2015-02-01     4545
```

MY query:

```
SELECT a.itemid,a.inventdimid,max(a.datephysical),a.transrefid
  FROM  a where dataareaid = 'ermi' 
group by a.itemid,a.inventdimid
```

it is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: But how do you come up with transrefid value? There's no transrefid 555 in the table...

Comment: I think he means `55555`

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ANSI standard `row_number()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by itemid, inventdimid
                                order by datephysical desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: best answer so far using row_number() to rank them internally

Answer (score 0):

Find max(a.datephysical) for each itemid, inventdimid combination, select all rows from that date.

```
SELECT itemid, inventdimid, datephysical, transrefid
FROM  a a1
where dataareaid = 'ermi'
  and datephysical = (select max(datephysical)
                      from a a2
                      where a1.itemid = a2.itemid
                        and a1.inventdimid = a2.inventdimid
                        and a2.dataareaid = 'ermi')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a temporary table with your `GROUP BY` and then join the original table with it.

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.*,T2.datephysical,T2.transrefid FROM 
(SELECT itemid,inventdimid 
         FROM TableName 
         GROUP BY itemid,inventdimid) T1 JOIN
(SELECT itemid,inventdimid,datephysical,transrefid
 FROM TableName) T2 ON T1.itemid=T2.itemid AND T1.inventdimid=T2.inventdimid
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the transrefid corresponding with the a.datephysical shown? This would be done by turning the column into a subquery:

```
SELECT a.itemid,a.inventdimid,max(a.datephysical),
(SELECT b.transrefid FROM MY_TABLE b where
b.datareaid = 'ermi' and b.itemid = a.itemid and b.inventdimid = a.itemid
and b.datephysical = max(a.datephysical)) as transrefid
FROM MY_TABLE a where dataareaid = 'ermi' 
group by a.itemid, a.inventdimid
```

Some databases may not support this syntax though and it will fail if there are more than one records with the same date.