# display max on one column but display multiple from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

how would i write a query to output the max column3 records for each corresponding record in column 1:

```
SELECT    t1.column1, t1.column2, MAX(t2.column3) as MAXcolumn3
FROM      table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2
ON        t1.column2 = t2.column2
Group by  t1.column1, t1.column2
```

RAW OUTPUT

```
column1 column2 column3
   a      aa      33
   a      ab      02
   a      ac      NULL
   b      ba      11
   b      bb      00
   c      ca      NULL
   c      cb      00
   d      da      NULL
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
column1 column2 column3
   a      aa      33
   a      ab      33
   a      ac      33
   b      ba      11
   b      bb      11
   c      ca      00
   c      cb      00
   d      da      NULL
```

Comment: What are your criteria for getting from the raw output to the desired output? Why `aa` rather than `ab`?

Comment: Possible duplicate:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607611/sql-group-by-and-max-and-other-values][1]

Comment: @Necreaux i want max on column 3 for the record in column1. Here a has  three rows and 33 is the max value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using the aggregate function `MAX()` as a window function:

```
SELECT column1, column2, MAX(column3) OVER ( PARTITION BY column1 ) AS MAXcolumn3
  FROM table1;
```

I don't know the precise schema of your table so I don't know if the above would return duplicates.

If you have two tables, then you might take your original query and do something similar with a subquery or CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, MAX(t2.column3) as MAXcolumn3
      FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 -- supposed to be table1?
        ON t1.column2 = t2.column2
     GROUP BY t1.column1, t1.column2
)
SELECT column1, column2, MAX(MAXcolumn3) OVER ( PARTITION BY column1 ) AS MAXcolumn3
  FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 2):

Join table1 to itself on `column1` to get all sibling rows, *then* left join to table2:

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, MAX(t3.column3) as MAXcolumn3
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2 ON t2.column1 = t1.column1
LEFT JOIN table2 t3 ON t3.column2 = t2.column2
GROUP BY t1.column1, t1.column2
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a2c4c/1)

Comment: The Maxcolumn3 should only display the max value for a particular value in t1.column1

Comment: t1.column2 = t2.column2 needs to be the join. t2 does not have column1

Comment: @user793468 what do you mean it doesn't have column1?? It's *the same table* - it's joining to itself, so it has to have it. Look at the linked demo (I made the column types all int for simplicity of inputting data, but the principle is sound) and you'll see this query works as you want it to.

Comment: I just noticed you are joining table1 with itself. I thought you were joining with table2. I meant to say table2 does not have column1

Comment: @user793468 but the query in your question is joining table1 with itself, and I assumed that the "raw output" was the contents of that table. "Table2" is not mentioned anywhere in your question. What is the actual situation?

Comment: Apologies if I was not clear in the begining... But column3 is in a different table(table2) and hence I have to join two separate tables to bring in column3. and column2 is common between table1 and table2

Comment: Any way to incorporate the table2?

Comment: @user793468 probably, but tell me what columns each table has. Is it table1 has column1 and column2, and table2 has column2 and column3?

Comment: Table1 has column1, column2 and Table2 has column2, column3

Comment: @user793468 now that SQLFiddle is back up, I've added a link to an SQLFiddle, which shows it working correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
select tt.*
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.column1 , t2.column2 
                                order by t1.column1 desc) as column3
      from table t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2
ON        t1.column2 = t2.column2
Group by  t1.column1, t1.column2
     ) tt
where tt.column3 = 1;
```

Comment: if this not meet you requirement then provide your table's data while you provided your query's data and your goal

Comment: I want to display the respective max record from column 3 for every distinct record in column 1. where and how are you getting the max record from column 3 for every record in column1?